# Fan not running when Ubuntu is running

Tags: overheating, fancontrol

I have an Acer Aspire 5315 laptop. The fan works when the computer starts up, but once it boots to Ubuntu the fan no longer works. After a few minutes the computer overheats and shuts down. I have Ubuntu 14.04.1 installed. If some on knows how to fix this please tell me how.

Comment: You could try this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175594. I am not sure if this will solve your problem so I place it here xD.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

I first saw it here: http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/2014/04/24/10-or-20-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

More info on TLP

http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html